# C++ round is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Возможно ли данная функция и как она будет работать?

```
int ViewHub::roundToInt( double param )
{
    return static_cast<int>( std::round( param ) );
}
```

на строчку `return`, показывает ошибку `round is not a member of 'std'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Округлит значение `param` до ближайшего целого - см. [тут](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round), а потом преобразует в целое - насколько сумеет это сделать с учетом разных диапазонов представлений `double` и `int`. Тут могут быть любые фокусы - типа, под VC++2015 эта функция для значения `3453642346.0` вернет `-2147483648`.

Зачем ее делать членом класса - не знаю; хозяин - барин...

Понятно, что для использования `round` должен быть включен соответствующий заголовочный файл, а компилятор - поддерживать C++11, начиная с которого эта функция появилась в стандарте.

Comment: немного подредактировал вопрос, а почему показывает ошибку тогда?

Comment: А вы включили `#include <cmath>`?

Comment: да он влючен поэтому и странно.

Comment: Компилятор поддерживает C++11?

Comment: @Harry, в недавнем его вопросе не поддерживал

Comment: ну вообще, установлен VS 2012, он на сколько мне уже известно, поддерживает C++11

Comment: Ну просто загляньте в его заголовочный файл `cmath`

Comment: Вот, почитайте тут - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/ru-RU/260e04fc-dd05-4a96-8953-9c6ea1ad62fb/cant-find-stdround-in-cmath?forum=vclanguage

Comment: как  я понял в общем, нужен VS 2013 минимум.